# I want to print an integer to the screen, add one to it and then print the answer to this for a given loop (say up until 10)

Tags: android

Rather than do this by just creating a lot of strings (which I've already managed), I want to add an integer and then print those list to the screen. At the moment, I'm just trying to get one integer on the screen without even adding it, but the app is "force closed" in the emulator. Why doesn't this work?

Code:

```
package com.monkeez.count;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Count extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        TextView countDisplay;
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        int counter = 1;
        countDisplay = new TextView(this);
        this.setContentView(countDisplay);
        countDisplay.setText("counter here");

    }
}
```

The log cat is thus:

```
09-01 09:54:07.051: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(279): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
09-01 09:54:07.051: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(279): CheckJNI is ON
09-01 09:54:07.401: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(279): --- registering native functions ---
09-01 09:54:08.891: DEBUG/dalvikvm(193): GC_EXPLICIT freed 320 objects / 19376 bytes in 109ms
09-01 09:54:09.041: DEBUG/PackageParser(65): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl48927.tmp
09-01 09:54:09.251: INFO/PackageManager(65): Removing non-system package:com.monkeez.count
09-01 09:54:09.251: INFO/ActivityManager(65): Force stopping package com.monkeez.count uid=10037
09-01 09:54:09.991: DEBUG/PackageManager(65): Scanning package com.monkeez.count
09-01 09:54:09.991: INFO/PackageManager(65): Package com.monkeez.count codePath changed from /data/app/com.monkeez.count-2.apk to /data/app/com.monkeez.count-1.apk; Retaining data and using new
09-01 09:54:10.011: INFO/PackageManager(65): /data/app/com.monkeez.count-1.apk changed; unpacking
09-01 09:54:10.054: DEBUG/installd(34): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.monkeez.count-1.apk' ---
09-01 09:54:10.511: DEBUG/dalvikvm(286): DexOpt: load 169ms, verify 64ms, opt 4ms
09-01 09:54:10.591: DEBUG/installd(34): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.monkeez.count-1.apk' (success) ---
09-01 09:54:10.602: WARN/PackageManager(65): Code path for pkg : com.monkeez.count changing from /data/app/com.monkeez.count-2.apk to /data/app/com.monkeez.count-1.apk
09-01 09:54:10.602: WARN/PackageManager(65): Resource path for pkg : com.monkeez.count changing from /data/app/com.monkeez.count-2.apk to /data/app/com.monkeez.count-1.apk
09-01 09:54:10.611: DEBUG/PackageManager(65):   Activities: com.monkeez.count.Count
09-01 09:54:10.650: INFO/ActivityManager(65): Force stopping package com.monkeez.count uid=10037
09-01 09:54:11.631: INFO/installd(34): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.monkeez.count-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.monkeez.count-1.apk@classes.dex
09-01 09:54:11.641: DEBUG/PackageManager(65): New package installed in /data/app/com.monkeez.count-1.apk
09-01 09:54:11.821: DEBUG/dalvikvm(65): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6733 objects / 446400 bytes in 140ms
09-01 09:54:12.561: INFO/ActivityManager(65): Force stopping package com.monkeez.count uid=10037
09-01 09:54:12.711: DEBUG/dalvikvm(126): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1940 objects / 106408 bytes in 121ms
09-01 09:54:13.351: WARN/RecognitionManagerService(65): no available voice recognition services found
09-01 09:54:13.831: DEBUG/dalvikvm(65): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4667 objects / 280056 bytes in 173ms
09-01 09:54:13.901: DEBUG/dalvikvm(165): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2326 objects / 125088 bytes in 1059ms
09-01 09:54:14.180: INFO/installd(34): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.monkeez.count-2.apk@classes.dex
09-01 09:54:14.271: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(279): Shutting down VM
09-01 09:54:14.290: DEBUG/dalvikvm(279): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
09-01 09:54:14.340: INFO/AndroidRuntime(279): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
09-01 09:54:15.350: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(291): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
09-01 09:54:15.350: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(291): CheckJNI is ON
09-01 09:54:15.740: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(291): --- registering native functions ---
09-01 09:54:16.960: INFO/ActivityManager(65): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.monkeez.count/.Count }
09-01 09:54:17.120: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(291): Shutting down VM
09-01 09:54:17.170: DEBUG/dalvikvm(291): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
09-01 09:54:17.250: INFO/AndroidRuntime(291): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
09-01 09:54:17.301: INFO/ActivityManager(65): Start proc com.monkeez.count for activity com.monkeez.count/.Count: pid=298 uid=10037 gids={}
09-01 09:54:18.611: WARN/ResourceType(298): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
09-01 09:54:18.620: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(298): Shutting down VM
09-01 09:54:18.620: WARN/dalvikvm(298): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.monkeez.count/com.monkeez.count.Count}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:201)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2817)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at com.monkeez.count.Count.onCreate(Count.java:19)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-01 09:54:18.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(298):     ... 11 more
09-01 09:54:18.940: WARN/ActivityManager(65):   Force finishing activity com.monkeez.count/.Count
09-01 09:54:19.470: WARN/ActivityManager(65): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{43fb6718 com.monkeez.count/.Count}
09-01 09:54:19.550: INFO/ARMAssembler(65): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00000000_00000000 [ 33 ipp] (47 ins) at [0x2de138:0x2de1f4] in 602730 ns
09-01 09:54:22.523: WARN/InputManagerService(65): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@43f92978
09-01 09:54:22.681: INFO/Process(298): Sending signal. PID: 298 SIG: 9
09-01 09:54:22.826: INFO/ActivityManager(65): Process com.monkeez.count (pid 298) has died.
```

And the Count Manifest.xml is thus:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.monkeez.count"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Count"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

Thanks

ps. it seems that the parser on this site doesn't like to render my xml file - you can see it at http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=W75ak3E9

Comment: HAve you written the countDisplay xml file...Access it using R.layout.CountDisplay

Comment: He doesn't need to write countDisplay.xml. He's explicitly declaring a textview then setting that to be the content. But @Adam: you need to post your stacktraces from the logcat. That will 90% of the time tell you exactly what's wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Christopher is right. you need to use;

countDisplay.setText(***String.valueOf(counter)***);

Comment: This fixed it - many thanks. I did try putting some text in that box, which worked, hence I realised that it must a variable type problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't added an [`<activity>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) tag for `Count` to your AndroidManifest.xml.

The output of `logcat` is probably telling you this (or another indicative error message).

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't match the logcat output above. The log suggests you're calling `countDisplay.setText()` with an `int`, rather than a `String`.